# GitHub: URL to raw files

Tags: eclipse, github

I have some Eclipse extension projects hosted by GitHub. These projects also include the related update sites. I thus need an URL to the raw data that Eclipse can use to download and install the plugins.

I used to use this url pattern

```
https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME/raw/BRANCH
```

like

```
https://github.com/lowcoupling/dono/raw/master
```

But it suddenly stopped to work

How am I supposed to to this now!?

Comment: try this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME

Comment: I am trying raw.githubusercontent.com/lowcoupling/dono but I get "400: Invalid request"

Answer (score 3):

The url is indeed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/projectname, but it only applies to files, not the project itself (which would return 400: Invalid request)

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/projectname/branchName/file
```

For instance:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VonC/compileEverything/master/make_env.sh

This is different from a [project archive (tarball or zip) download](https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-archive-a-repository), which does download the full repo.
See **[get archive link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link)**:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

with:

- `archive_format`  string  Can be either tarball or zipball.
  Default: tarball
- `ref`     string  A valid Git reference.
  Default: the repository’s default branch (usually master)

For instance:

https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/compileEverything/zipball/master

Comment: Is there any way to get the url of the folder ?! That is what i need for the Eclipse update site

Comment: @lowcoupling no, you have to get the all repo (and extract the folder you want). Or you do a sparse clone, but that is a git clone operation.

Comment: So bad :( I guess I will have to rely on Google Drive

Comment: I can't use Google Drive! As it seems there is no way to have a clean url to a folder :( How may I address this problem?

Comment: @lowcoupling why not downloading the repo archive as I mentioned? It will include the folder you want.

Comment: Eclipse has a built in plugin installation manager. The majority of users expect to have an url to the update site they can provide to the installation manager. Downloading the whole code and locally refer it is very unusual

Comment: Then this is basically a hosting problem, not a programming problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I use Bitbucket's [support for static sites](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Publishing+a+Website+on+Bitbucket) to host an Eclipse update site.

Github has [Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually), which seems even more flexible.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this tarball url - https://github.com/lowcoupling/dono/tarball/master

Or the zipfile url - https://api.github.com/repos/lowcoupling/dono/zipball/master

Comment: hi and thank you for your kind answer. It actually doesn't solve my issue. It only allow me to download the whole repository but what I need is an url Eclipse can use to access the UpdateSite project and download the binaries itself

Comment: I have tried https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lowcoupling/dono/master But I get "Invalid Request"