# GitHub: raw.githubusercontent returning invalid request

Tags: git, github

I am trying to get a valid URL to the raw data of a git hub repository like

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lowcoupling/dono/master

What I get is an `400: invalid request` HTTP response

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24721940/6309

Answer (score 0):

The good URL schema is:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/REPONAME/BRANCHNAME/FILENAME
```

Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lowcoupling/dono/master/README.md

You just missed the filename.