# Where to host Eclipse Update Site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a couple of Eclipse extension projects hosted on GitHub. The problem is that I can't see where to host the related update site. It is in fact not possible on GitHub to have a direct url (raw) to a folder (the UpdateSite PRoject) as you can see here [GitHub: URL to raw files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721575/github-url-to-raw-files). It seems the same thing holds for Google Drive :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub: URL to raw files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721575/github-url-to-raw-files)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

I switched to GitHub Pages after Bintray has shut down.
This is the new post about that:
https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2021/03/publishing-an-eclipse-p2-composite-repository-on-github-pages/

OLD:

I now use bintray and I documented the whole process for publishing a composite update site to bintray here: http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2016/02/publish-an-eclipse-p2-composite-repository-on-bintray/

OLD 2:

I use sourceforge for the update site (aka p2 repository) of all my projects.  I recently published a blog post detailing all the steps to achieve that http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2015/01/publish-an-eclipse-p2-repository-on-sourceforge-with-rsync/

Comment: Bintray services have been discontinued as of 2021: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/ GitHub pages should still work, though. The fact that you can't access raw folders is actually not a problem when setting up a P2 update site (you can't view the folder directly, but the update manager doesn't actually need to look at the folder)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of that. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options I guess: SourceForge, Amazon S3 (with  CloudFront), Bintray.